# Loading an AIR Native Extension ( .ane ) at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am currently building an application that loads .swf and .swc as 'plugins', for either data or code. I'm sometimes loading .swf including AIR classes ( which is fine since the base application is written for AIR ), including related ressources.

However, I haven't found any way to load a .ane at runtime.

I've been looking around without being able to come up with a good solution. I can unzip the .ane and load the libs it contains, but there is no way I can load a .dll, which is critical.

Any solution or workaround comes to mind ? Is that even possible ?
Also, assuming I would move the .dll contained in the .ane, I have no clue for the target location I should move it to, so just that would be a step forward in the attempt :)

Comment: I don't think that is possible right now. The big difference is that SWFs or SWCs are compiled AS3 code. ANEs are compiled native code (on whatever platform you are). Have you tried compiling the ANE into an external SWF loaded at runtime?

Comment: In fact the .ane isn't even native code 'as is', you can simply rename a .ane as a .zip and you will see that it actually include an AS3 library (.swf) _and_ a .dll which is native code. 
What I have tried is loading the swf part of the .ane, which works fine, and I can move the .dll around, I just don't know where the AIR player is going to look for it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. But you can try do two things as experiment:

1. From ANE load in-bundle library (e.g.: jar if Java for Android) if this behavior supported in you target platform;
2. Create in AS3 dynamic interface* instead classic (and recommended) static.

*interface = bridge

Also I highly recommend use Interfaces (real :) ) in 2.

Also in any part you can implement an interpreter for any language like js, py, basic.

Comment: Actually that would be one neat solution. 
If I understood correctly, there is one bottleneck though : .ane needs to be developped especially for the target 'bridge' dll, or require somewhat heavy implementation to be compatible, meaning I can't actually allow external content to load generic-made .ane ( such as various open-source .ane or projects you can see on the net , like gamepad support etc)

Comment: The .ane is a collection of several couples of {(AS3-bridge) + (dll/ndll/a/etc - native lib using native API) + (embedded assets and third-party libs)} for all you targeting platforms. If the targeted native API support loading some external staff then you can use it ;)